# GetPivotData function is no longer occurs automatically

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table, excel-2013

I am building a dashboard in Excel 2013 by connecting to cells in a large number of pivot tables.  Normally all I have to do is put `=` in a cell and then click on a cell in the pivot table and it will automatically create the formula:

`=GETPIVOTDATA("Max Baseline",'Template Pivots'!$K$4,"Category","Apples","Measure","Combined").`

But today I when I started working Excel now treats the pivot tables like they are range values.  Instead of `GETPIVOTDATA` it produces `='Template Pivots'!P5`.

Has anyone had this happen to them before?  Did I accidentally disable the automatic `GETPIVOTDATA` function?  I started building the table in Excel 2010 but upgraded to Excel 2013, could that have thrown things off?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two places to change the setting (which is global).

1. In the Pivot Ribbon, the option is in the `Options` menu.
2. It is also in the general settings for Excel, `Options->Formulas`

[image: options]

[image: general options]

Comment: I think the setting is for all pivot tables no matter where you access it from. Some quick testing confirms it. I'm also using Excel 2013.

Comment: Thank you very much!  Solved the problem immediately!